# How do we promote selenium users to post questions in the form of questions?

Tags: support, subjective-questions, selenium

I've noticed that there are a lot of the Selenium and Selenium 2 questions that have a title that is not in the form of the question and that, in the body, there really isn't a definitive "How do I" or "What do I" kind of question.

Is this something that should be flagged for moderation or should there be some sort of Wiki link provided for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach - don't know if it's the best approach:
Comment, asking for more detail. If no more detail is forthcoming, vote to close, as the question is unclear.

Hopefully though, the poster will clarify (often in comments). Maybe edit the question to include their responses so it's easier for people to read.

I think it takes practice and feedback to write a good question - and sometimes it's not until someone else asks that you realise you left the point out of your question.

Comment: +1 You need to take them on a case by case basis. I hate to vote to close too early, especially early in the history of the site, because I think people should be allowed to fix where their post is in err. But you have to draw the line somewhere (maybe a day or two) and if it still isn't up to par, it's time to close it up, because we don't want to leave the impression that it's okay to ask unanswerable questions.